# How can i pass data from middleware to router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, jwt

We have authenticateToken middleware in getpost router. The authenticateToken middleware validates the token.

If the token has expired, the if(err) conditional statement is executed. At this time, the accessToken is issued again through the refreshtoken.

I would like to pass this issued accessToken to the router. console.log(accessToken); How do I fix the code to do this?

this is my code

(index.js)

```
    router.post('/getpost', authenticateToken, async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        console.log(accessToken);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error); // status 500
      }
    });
```

(middleware.js)

```
      exports.authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            jwt.verify(
              refreshToken,
              process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
              async (err, user) => {
                if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
                const accessToken = await generateAccessToken(users); // i want to pass this  accessToken to router
                console.log('accessToken::::', accessToken);
            
              },
            );
            res.json({accessToken: accessToken});
          }
          req.user = user;
          next();
        });
      };

      function generateAccessToken(user) {
        return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: '55s'});
      }




    app.post("/token", (req, res) => {
      const refreshToken = req.body.token;
      console.log("refreshToken:", refreshToken);
      if (refreshToken == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
      if (!refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken)) return res.sendStatus(403);
      jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        const accessToken = generateAccessToken({ name: user.name });
        res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
      });
    });
```

Comment: can you update the code in question with your updated local code, so i can help you with what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```js
exports.authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            jwt.verify(
              refreshToken,
              process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
              async (err, user) => {
                if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
                const accessToken = await generateAccessToken(users); // i want to pass this  accessToken to router
                // Adding token to the req object
                req.accessToken = accessToken
                // Added this
                next()
              },
            );

            res.json({accessToken: accessToken});
          } else { 
            req.user = user;
            next();
          }
        });
      };

      function generateAccessToken(user) {
        return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: '55s'});
      }
```

You pass token using req object, and get the token in route like this

```js
router.post('/getpost', authenticateToken, async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        // Access the token through req object
        console.log(req.accessToken);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error); // status 500
      }
    });
```

Edit: Wrote example based on code in question

Comment: @jackvolten I edited the answer, please check it out

Comment: i try again but this error occure: accessToken is not defined

Comment: @jackvolten accessToken is not defined because `jwt.verify(...)` is async, and `next()` is called before accessToken is set. I edited the answer once again, I added `else` statement in the first callback and `next()` call in the refresh token callback.

Comment: oh thank you!! it works!!!  but i wonder is it necessary?  res.json({accessToken: accessToken});????

Comment: My advice is to make an another route for refreshing expired access token. How i understood, function of your middleware is to check if access token is valid or not, and to protect your route, so that is what it should do, and only that, If token is valid, everything is ok, and request continues, and if not, you return 403.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232082/discussion-between-jack-volten-and-scovic).